# Lack of docker-current file cause docker service cannot be start in Centos 7

Tags: docker

I tried to start docker service after I installed it:

```
sudo systemctl start docker
```

and an error occurred here:

> ● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine    Loaded:
>   loaded (/etc/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset:
>   disabled)    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-05-16
>   14:40:57 CST; 8s ago
>        Docs: http://docs.docker.com   Process: 1002 ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker-current daemon --exec-opt
>   native.cgroupdriver=systemd $OPTIONS $DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS
>   $DOCKER_NETWORK_OPTIONS $ADD_REGISTRY $BLOCK_REGISTRY
>   $INSECURE_REGISTRY (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)  Main PID: 1002
>   (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
>
> May 16 14:40:57 iZm5ej22ekoik4surc9daeZ systemd[1]: Starting Docker
>   Application Container Engine... May 16 14:40:57
>   iZm5ej22ekoik4surc9daeZ systemd[1002]: Failed at step EXEC spawning
>   /usr/bin/docker-current: No such file or directory May 16 14:40:57
>   iZm5ej22ekoik4surc9daeZ systemd[1]: docker.service: main process
>   exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC May 16 14:40:57
>   iZm5ej22ekoik4surc9daeZ systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application
>   Container Engine. May 16 14:40:57 iZm5ej22ekoik4surc9daeZ systemd[1]:
>   Unit docker.service entered failed state. May 16 14:40:57
>   iZm5ej22ekoik4surc9daeZ systemd[1]: docker.service failed.

It seems that start docker service need docker-current file, but it does not exist. But I could start docker by run this command:

```
docker daemon
```

So what confused me is what docker-current file do.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved by re-install the latest docker.